# MKMapView for Mac (non-iOS apps)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, mkmapview, geocoding

does anybody know a way of implementing something like the MKMapView (existing for iOS) for pure Mac applications? I tried adding it and I'm used to using it for iOS apps, but it's not listed in the Object Library.

Thanks

Comment: Also, there is NSPopover for Mac applications, but not iOS apps. Do I really have to write this programmatically (which I can't) or is there a hidden tool?

Answer (score 0):

In respond to your `NSPopover` question: even there's private library can do this, NEVER use it, you're risking being reject from App Store, and even if you're lucky enough to pass, you never know when in the future will Apple remove it.

Comment: So, is it not possible to have something similar to NSPopover? I.e. when pressing a button, an NSTableView pops over the content of my app (for iPad preferably).

Comment: I asked the NSPopover question somewhere else, and found an answer. Thought you might want to know (I did :]) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989486/nspopover-for-ios)