# NSPopover for iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there something similar to NSPopover for iOS apps? It appears in the Object library for Mac but not for iPhone nor iPad, although I have downloaded apps using this (or at least some very similar) feature.

So my question: *Is there a legit way to implement this?*

Answer (score 3):

`UIPopoverController` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Remember, UIPopoverController is iPad only!

Answer (score 2):

There is `UIPopOverController`, but its use is restricted to iPads:

> Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html))

For iPhone/iPod touch, you could use an external framework, like [WEPopOver](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover).

Answer (score 0):

There is they are called UIPopovers,

Heres a tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iykxemuxbk

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of those Googling this, `UIPopoverController` is **now available for both iPhone and iPad**. You can make popovers that look the same on both (as of iOS 9, I believe).

**Step 1**: Include `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` and `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` on your class definition

**Step 2:** Override the presentation somewhere in your class like this:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
  return .none
}
```

**Step 3:** When you present a view controller, you tell it to use `popover` style. Something like this:

```
//I pull my popover from a separate storyboard, but any modal view will do
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Popovers", bundle: nil)
let modal = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnyPickerModal") as! AnyPickerVC
modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

let pc = modal.popoverPresentationController
pc?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
pc?.sourceView = <your button or view you tap to show the popover>
pc?.sourceRect = <your button or view>.bounds

//How big the popover should be
modal.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 180)

pc?.delegate = self

self.present(modal, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Your presented modal will show up as a popover on **both** iPhone and iPad. Attached is a screenshot from my iPhone app.

[image]

Happy coding!